# Why was Bruce Campbell in all three Spider-Man movies?

Tags: analysis, spider-man-trilogy, bruce-campbell

Bruce Campbell was in all three of the Sam Raimi movies, but as different bit characters in each one.  Why was he used in all three movies?

Comment: he was a friend of Sam raimi ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There were a couple of reasons for this.

1) Sam Raimi (director) and Bruce Campbell are good friends and Bruce normally gets cameo's in his films.

2) There was a rumor before and after Spider-man 3 Bruce Campbell was going to become Mysterio as Mysterio constantly blames Spider-man for his failed acting and stunt gigs.[(source)](http://www.accesshollywood.com/bruce-campbell-spider-man-4-shooting-in-january-villainous-role-in-the-works_article_22863)

Comment: It's basically a tradition between the two, who, as Oliver C. notes, broke into showbiz together with the early Evil Dead films.

Answer (score 8):

From an **[interview](http://www.ign.com/articles/2002/12/18/an-interview-with-bruce-campbell) with *Bruce Campbell***:

> **When did you first meet the Raimis?**
>
> - *I was born in the same hospital as Sam Raimi – the William Beaumont Hospital in Royal Oaks.*
>
>   ***I met Sam in junior high** – very briefly while I was with a friend of his – and he was dressed as Sherlock Holmes, playing with dolls. **I thought he was a creepy weirdo, and I avoided him, officially, until drama class in high school, in 1975.***
>
>   ***Sam was very much into magic, and I was his assistant at a couple of magic shows.** Then, I think Sam made a logical transition into film being the ultimate sleight of hand.*
>
> **And this is what – late '60s, early '70s?**
>
> - *Well, for Sam, I think he started doing home movies in the early '70s. I did them in the early '70s, and we started making – then I met other guys in our neighborhood who had been making Super-8 movies longer than us, [**Scott Spiegel**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0818547/) being one of them.... [**Josh Becker**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0065471/), who was Sam's neighbor...*
>
>   *... **so there was a weird group of about six of us, who wound up teaming up and making Super-8 movies on weekends – almost every weekend.***

and

> **So, around this time, is it a bit apocryphal that you also babysat for the Raimis?**
>
> - *Well, I took [**Ted**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001646/) [Sam Raimi's younger brother] to cello lessons occasionally, but I think they made me do that because I ate dinner over there all the time.*
>
> **Just out of convenience, because you were always filming?**
>
> - *Yeah. We'd shoot in Sam's living room, and eat dinner, and then whenever the Raimis were working and Sam was busy I'd pick up Ted at cello lessons. I think I've known Ted since he was about 9.*

---

So,

- *Sam Raimi* and *Bruce Campbell* have known each other since High School
- They started making movies together in the 70's.
- *Bruce Campbell* visited the Raimis so often they used him as a babysitter for *Sam's* younger brother ;)

Comment: I think you missed the main point and detailed less important point......!!mysterio!!

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I don't think Bruce Campbell's cameos in the trilogy had much to do with a possible larger role in _Spider-Man 4_. Bruce has appeared in Sam Raimi movies [since the 70's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Campbell#Filmography), and he will also cameo in Raimi's upcoming [Oz The Great and Powerful](http://www.craveonline.com/film/interviews/192115-comic-con-2012-sami-raimi-on-oz-the-great-and-powerful).

Comment: Considering that both Campbell and Raimi achieved international fame only after doing the movie Evil Dead together, I can't see how they aren't best buddies...